# asynchronous processing (callbacks in libraries + controllers)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-handling, titanium, promise

My code is working fine, but I do not like at all.

I would like to split one file into two files, one containing webServices and another one with a controller.

My file do something like this:

### File: Validacion.js (controller)

```
// Load next view
var MainView = Alloy.createController('index').getView('tabGroup');


// this a function call when I click a button "validar" on Validación View.
function btnClick(){

    var url = 'www.cocoloco.com/whatever';

    var webService = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function(e){

            // open new view
            MainView.open();

            // close actual view
            $.tabValidacion.close();
            $.tabValidacion = null;

        },
        onerror: function(e){
            alert('onerror: ' + e.error);
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });

    webService.open('POST', url);
    webService.send();      

}
```

But I would like to do something like this below (divided in two files: webServices.js -library- and validation.js -controller-).

The problem is that I always have the message "error" because I pass throught "success = webServices.protocol();" but as far as it is "asynchronous" it doesn't stop and goes to following line of code without having server answer yet.

### File: webServices.js (library)

```
exports.protocol = function(){

    var url = 'www.cocoloco.com/whatever';

    var webService = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function(e){

            // on sucess exit with true
            return(true);

        },
        onerror: function(e){
            alert('onerror: ' + e.error);
            // on sucess exit with false
            return(false);
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });

    webService.open('POST', url);
    webService.send();      

}
```

### File: Validacion.js (controller)

```
// Load next view
var MainView = Alloy.createController('index').getView('tabGroup');

function btnClick(){

    var webServices = require('webServices');

    var success = webServices.protocol();

    if(success){

        // open new view
        MainView.open();

    // close actual view
        $.tabValidacion.close();
        $.tabValidacion = null;

    }else{
        alert('error');
    }
}
```

I have thought about two possible options:

- Using promises.
- Fire a new event on "success" and use that event run another callback function (in this function I open the new view and close the previous one).

I do not know how difficult is this as far as the event is one file (library) and the callback function in another one (controller)

I have never used any of these solutions, so I do not know how "good" they are.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Promises make callbacks obsolete, imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback approach works fine in most cases. Just pass the function as a parameter, you can return an object containing anything from a success message to responseText and status.

**webServices.js**

```
exports.protocol = function(callback) {
    var url = 'www.cocoloco.com/whatever';

    var webService = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function(e){
            // on success call callback
            callback({ success: true });
        },
        onerror: function(e){
            // on error call callback
            callback({ success: false });
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });

    webService.open('POST', url);
    webService.send();      
}
```

**Validacion.js**

```
function btnClick(){
    var webServices = require('webServices');

    webServices.protocol(function(e) {
        if(e.success){
            // open new view
            MainView.open();

            // close actual view
            $.tabValidacion.close();
            $.tabValidacion = null;
        } else {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Now, It is more "profesional" as far as functionality is disengaged but I think that probably many people would think that first version was more understandable.
I was thinking about giving some "alert" to the user on success, so "alert('contratulations!');" before "MainView.open();" but alert doesn't stop processing so I think I have to use another callback for that. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped, but all I did was replacing returns with a callback, the rest is still your code. I don't understand what makes it less understandable now. Using returns for asynchronous calls does simply not work, regardless how easy it is to read. So please let me know what you expect to make this an acceptable answer.

Comment: I can not expect anything else, your answer was just perfect.

Comment: I see, so please mark the answer as correct, I thought this was not closed yet ;)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I should mark it as right. Done. Thanks for your help.